# ActionScript 3.0 If Else MouseOver

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to code like this:

```
If(MouseOver){
stop();
}
```

Because I have a rotating globe that has been masked so I can't make it a movie clip, today is my first time making flash and coding actionscript3.0. So I don't even know if where is the instance name located.
If it is possible I want my rotating globe to be drag and droped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need an example that

- Stops Rotating on Mouse over.
- Starts Rotating on Mouse out.
- Can be dragged around & dropped.

Here is the snippet :

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var globe:Sprite = new Sprite();

var isMouseOver:Boolean = false;

globe.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
globe.graphics.drawRect(-50,-50,100,100);
globe.graphics.endFill();

globe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(e) { globe.startDrag();});
globe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP ,  function(e) { globe.stopDrag(); });
globe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e) { isMouseOver = true; });
globe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , function(e) { isMouseOver = false; });

globe.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e) {globe.rotation += isMouseOver? 0 : 1;});

addChild(globe);
```

Comment: Though this is example code, it is an extremely bad idea to have anonymous functions.  How would you remove the listener?  This could really lock up code from the GC.  Since the programmer seems to be a bit new to the concepts, can you amend the answer to show how a named function would be used?